# How to set index of char pointer array to a char pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, token

I'm tokenizing by commas, which gives me char * as an output in a while loop. How do I assign each of these char pointers in the while loop to the index of a char pointer []?

Pseudocode:

```
char * p;
char * args[30];
int i = 0;
while(p!=NULL){
    p = strtok(NULL,",");
    args[i] = p; //attempt 1
    *(args + i) = p; //attempt 2
    strcpy(p,args[i]); //attempt 3
    i++;
}
```

Error:
I print out the value of p and after printing index 0, it fails. Here is my code for printing it out:

```
 for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
      printf("%s \n",args[j]);
 }
```

Here is my error:
"0 g" when my input is "g m n" and it prints out
Segmentation fault: 11.

Comment: Are you asking what type should `args` have?

Comment: You might want to learn that `args[i]` is equivalent to `*(args + i)`, so both those assignment will do the same.

Comment: @AlexLop. Sorry, realized I forgot to intialize args in the pseudocode. I'm asking how I can set args[i] to the value of p. I'm having issues understanding pointers.

Comment: As for your problem, maybe you could please elaborate on it? What makes you think that those attempts won't work (oh and by the way the `strcpy` variant will most definitely not work)? Can you maybe try  to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that contains whatever problem you have, and show it to us?

Comment: If so then 'attempt1' is equal to 'attempt2' and seems to be correct.

Comment: As a corollary, be advised that strtok is not re-entrant, so if this is one thread or instance of strtok running in the same address space, you may get undefined results.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've run the code with the three attempts, none of which have worked. I've included more information on the errors I'm getting as well.

Comment: Where is the first call to `strtok()`? It seems like it's missing from your code.

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is mostly correct, but I think your problem is that you're using `strtok()` incorrectly. Upon its first call, `strtok()` expects a string and delimiters. Subsequent calls expect `NULL` and delimiters.

I modified your C "pseudo-code" to a working program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* p;
    char* args[30];
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    char input[30];
    puts("Please enter a string:");
    scanf("%29s", &input); /* get a string to break up */

    p = args[i++] = strtok(input, ",");  /* first call to strtok() requires the input */

    while(p!=NULL && i < 30) { /* added bounds check to avoid buffer overruns */
        p = strtok(NULL,","); /* subsequent calls expect NULL */
        args[i] = p; /* this is the best way to assign values to args, but it's equivalent to your attempt 2*/
        i++;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("%s \n",args[j]);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** I just realized that my original code used an uninitialized pointer `p`. This is undefined behavior, and I have corrected the code.

Comment: For simmetry with the instruction just before the while loop, the while body could have been written as  `args[ i++ ] = strtok( NULL, "," );`.

Comment: @mw215 True. I just didn't change the loop from the original post. If this were my program, I probably would have done that.